# ¿Hacer Merge de datos a Documentos EXCEL?

Tags: java, jsf, excel, apache-poi

Buen día, sucede que necesito hacer una funcionalidad que modifique unos campos que estan definidos en un documento excel en JAVA al igual que lo estoy haciendo en este momento con documentos word (.docx), la verdad sé que hay una API pero no tengo idea de donde encontrarla ni como funciona, la idea es que haga lo siguiente, colocaré el ejemplo del Word ya que se quiere lo mismo pero en documentos excel:

El documento WORD, la plantilla está hecha de la siguiente manera, por ejemplo:

```
Buen día <item2> <item3>, su número de solicitud es el <item1>, cuando la evaluemos se le informará

Datos del solicitante:

    Nombre: <item2>
    Apellido: <item3>
    Cargo: <item4>
    Institución: <item5>
```

En el programa se ejecuta y digamos, hace una propuesta para que envien más juegos a su universidad, entonces generamos la solicitud y le creamos el documento y quedaria:

```
Buen día Fabian Montoya, su número de solicitud es el 123456789, cuando la evaluemos se le informará

Datos del solicitante:

    Nombre: Fabian
    Apellido: Montoya
    Cargo: Estudiante
    Institución: Universidad Nacional
```

Y listo, se le genera el documento y se le da para que descargue, así funciona el de documentos word, ahora necesito poder hacer lo mismo pero con plantillas de documentos que estan hechas en excel.

Con la misma estructura, cambiar  que estén allí por datos que manejamos desde el programa, no sé si me hago entender, espero su ayuda, lo he buscaod durante dos horas y no consigo nada.

Comment: Para los word uso la libreria org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.* por si puede ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo hice, quedó así.

```
static String ruta1 = "D:/", document1 = "FOR_001_EXAMPLE", type1 = ".xlsx";
static String Documento = "", NewDocumento = "";

public static void XLSX(String Ubicacion) throws IOException {

        Ubicacion = Ubicacion.replace("\\", "/"); //Convierto todos los \ en / para congruir en direcciones
        try {
            File Fil = new File(Ubicacion); //Se crea un archivo File
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(Fil); //Se crea archivo FileInput para la lectura
            // Crear el objeto que tendra el libro de Excel
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            /*
         * Obtenemos la primera pestaña a la que se quiera procesar indicando el indice.
         * Una vez obtenida la hoja excel con las filas que se quieren leer obtenemos el iterator
         * que nos permite recorrer cada una de las filas que contiene.
             */
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            Row row;
            // Recorremos todas las filas para mostrar el contenido de cada celda
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = rowIterator.next();
                // Obtenemos el iterator que permite recorres todas las celdas de una fila
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                Cell celda;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    celda = cellIterator.next();
                    // Dependiendo del formato de la celda el valor se debe mostrar como String, Fecha, boolean, entero...
                    switch (celda.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(celda)) {
                                // System.out.println(celda.getDateCellValue());
                            } else {
                                //System.out.println(celda.getNumericCellValue());
                            }
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            String item = "";
                            item = celda.getStringCellValue(); //Tomamos el valor de la celda
                            if (item.startsWith("<") && item.endsWith(">")) { //validamos que el contenido de la celda comience por < y termine en >
                                item = item.toLowerCase(); //Hago todo el item en minuscula
                                item = item.replace(">", "");
                                item = item.replace("<", "");
                                System.out.println("ITEM: "+item);
                                Merge(celda, item); //enviamos donde se le cambiará el item por el valor
                            }
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            System.out.println(celda.getBooleanCellValue());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // cerramos el libro excel
            file.close();
            //Se genera el nuevo archivo con los datos cambiados
            NewDocumento = "A01_" + "MergeFULL_" + document1 + "_SASPRUEBA_XLSX" + type1; //Creamos el nombre del documento
            NewDocumento = ruta1 + NewDocumento; //Agregamos el nombre del documento a la ruta donde se almacena
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(NewDocumento); //Doy la ruta y el nombre del archivo nuevo que se generará
            workbook.write(fileOut); //Escribo el nuevo archivo
            fileOut.close(); //Cierro el archivo

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex);
        }
    }

    public static void Merge(Cell cell, String item) {
        if (item.equals("item1")) {
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue("Fabian Dario Montoya");
        } else if (item.equals("item3")) {
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue("Excel_GO");
        } else {
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue("Item_not_found");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, InvalidFormatException {

        Documento = ruta1 + document1 + type1.toLowerCase();
        //Documento = ruta2+document2+type2;

        if (Documento.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
            XLSX(Documento);
            System.out.println("====??? GENERADO DOCUMENT XLSX ???======");
        } else if (Documento.endsWith(".xls")) {
            XLS(Documento);
            System.out.println("====??? GENERADO DOCUMENT XLS ???======");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Document not have the correct format!, please check it.");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La misma librería te permite crear documentos en Excel y o modificar, solo busca en la web "generar excel con apache poi en java" hay demasiados ejemplos, es que no entiendo bien que es lo que quieres hacer en el Excel.

Se me ocurre algo así habria que adaptarlo para que no recorra todo el excel...

```
    //Recorrido por filas
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        rowIndex = row.getRowNum();

       int rowIndex2 = rowIndex +1;
       Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
       //Recorrido por columnas
       while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
           String valorCelda = cell.getStringCellValue().trim();
           if(valorcelda.equals("<item9>")){
                //Cambiamos valor de la celda
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Quiero cambiar celdas donde tengo digamos <item9> por el valor del item9, no sé, digamos mi nombre, y genero el nuevo excel con esos datos cambiados, donde en lugar de decir <item9> va a decir mi nombre, ¿si me hago entender?

Comment: ya lo edité, a ver si te da una idea, no lo he intentado pero con poi no puedes obtener directamente la celda que quieres si no tienes un indice, con rowIndex puedes limitar  hasta que fila hace la busqueda igual deberias obtener la celda y limitarlo porque si no hara recorrido a todas las celdas y puede que se cicle. No he hecho algo asi, pero es una idea que te puedo dar.